# Will a question about why a plant flowers only after rain be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

With regards to [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24967/plant-only-flowers-after-rain-and-not-from-being-watered-what-plant-is-it) about identifying a plant found in a garden in south India wich only flowers after rain, I'm planning to ask in a separate question *why* it does that.

Will that be on-topic?

Is it better to ask it in Biology SE?

Comment: Hi Fiksdal. It's kind of you to ask here, as it can be hard to know the right site for your question, especially one of this type. I'm glad you posted it at our site! Obviously the identification is on-topic. I'm only one community member, but I think the follow-up will be too, as it will be interesting to a lot of gardeners, like me. I'll be looking forward to learning more about your plant!

Comment: @Sue Thank you for your comment :) I am also looking forward to learning more about it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it will depend on the type of answer you expect. Our help center has this text in the "don't ask" section:

> plant biology, beyond what is generally gardening knowledge (try [Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com) instead)

So if you're just looking for the environmental trigger that causes the plant to flower after rain, that would be on-topic here. If you're looking for the environmental trigger **and** how that trigger causes changes in the biochemistry of the plant **and** how those changes eventually lead to flowering, then that would belong on [Biology Stack Exchange](http://biology.stackexchange.com).

An analogy would be the concept of [forcing](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=forcing), using an artificial environment to satisfy a plant's requirements at specific points in its growth cycle. An example is chilling bulbs so as to have flowering Hyacinth or Narcissus at Christmastime. A biologist might know exactly what's happening internally in the bulb, but as a gardener I just need to know when to put the bulbs in the refrigerator and how long to keep them there.

Comment: That is very clear,  thank you!

Comment: I agree, very clear indeed! Thanks Niall!